# Return resolved deferred from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm animating an automated conversation with a bot.

When the first message ("Hi there, take a look at this!") has been printed, I want to go to the next function `.then()`. However I don't know how to set up the `r.resolve()` in this case, it's like nested or something.

```
var messages = [
    "Hi there, take a look at this!",
    "Enter your address",
    "blah blah"
];

function printLetters(target, message, index, interval, n) {

    r = $.Deferred();
    $('#m'+n).fadeIn();

    if (index < message.length) {
        $(target).append(message[index++]);
        setTimeout(function () {
            printLetters(target, message, index, interval, n);
        }, interval);
    } else {
        r.resolve();
    }
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;

    return r;

}

function printMessage(n) {
    r = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#m'+n+'>p').empty();
        r = printLetters('#m'+n+'>p', messages[n-1], 0, 40, n);
    }, 400);
    return r;
}

function startConversation() {
    printMessage(1)
        .then(showThumb1AndTapButton)
        .then(showThumb2AndScroll)
        .then(choosePaymentMethod)
        .then(enterAddress);
}

startConversation();
```

In this case, I want to get from `printMessage(1)` to the next `.then()` function, but I'm not sure how.

I'm not sure how to return the resolved `r` if the message has finished printing from the other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, define your variables, use `var` in the needed scope for each variable.

The problem is how you're handling the `r` variable. You're creating the deferred and storing it on `r`, returning `r` and then, 400ms after the function ended, creating a new `r` (because the previous `r` haven't been defined with `var`, this one is other variable in the timeout's handler function) with the output of `printLetters` which is other deferred... that last `r` has nothing to do with the value returned by `printMessage`.

I would suggest you to define your `r` (or other name more descriptive) as global (outside any function), create the deferred object just once and then work always with this variable.

**Update**

Since you have several functions that need to return a deferred, you could just pass the deferred as an argument. The point is to be consistent with the variables. For example (not tested, take the suggestiong and try it yourself):

```
function printMessage(n) {
    var r = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#m'+n+'>p').empty();
        printLetters(r, '#m'+n+'>p', messages[n-1], 0, 40, n); <--var needed for this r to be defined inside here
    }, 400);
    return r;
}
```

And then

```
function printLetters(r, target, message, index, interval, n) {
    ...
    ...
    r.resolve(); <--Note this is the parameter r
}
```

No need to return anything or creating a second deferred, you're working with the same object created and returned by `printMessage`.

Comment: Oh woops, I forgot to use `var` before them. In the other functions I made, they have `var`. Still, I don't know how to get to the next function?